# activiti extensionElements of user tasks read/write api's

Tags: activiti

I'm having one workflow where I need to stare some custom information inside user tasks. So I used extensionElement as below:

```
         <userTask id="writeReportTask" name="Write monthly financial report" activiti:assignee="${assignee}" activiti:owner="${owner}">
            <extensionElements>
                <activiti:field name="clientName" stringValue="${clientName}" />
                <activiti:field name="companyName" stringValue="${companyName}" />
            </extensionElements>
          </userTask>

         <userTask id="financeReportTask" name="review monthly financial report" activiti:assignee="${assignee}" activiti:owner="${owner}">
            <extensionElements>
                <activiti:field name="clientName" stringValue="${clientName}" />
                <activiti:field name="companyName" stringValue="${companyName}" />
            </extensionElements>
          </userTask>
```

In above workflow I'm going to store two custom properties "clientName" and "dueDate".
1. How to read/write "clientName" and "companyName" value through API for currently activated tasks?
2. In the above example I'm storing string value(stringValue="${clientName}"). Is there a way to store list of values and how to store/retrieve list of values through API?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:**

**${clientName}** and **${companyName}** are process variables. You can read/write from current execution:

*Read:*

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(String.valueOf(processInstanceId)).active().singleResult();
Map<String, Object> variablesMap = runtimeService.getVariables(task.getExecutionId());
String clientName = variablesMap.get("clientName");
String companyName = variablesMap.get("companyName");
```

*Write:*

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(String.valueOf(processInstanceId)).active().singleResult();
runtimeService.setVariable(task.getExecutionId(), "clientName", clientName);
runtimeService.setVariable(task.getExecutionId(), "companyName", companyName);
```

Or you can store variables to your own database and read/write from it.

```
<userTask id="writeReportTask" name="Write monthly financial report" activiti:assignee="${assignee}" activiti:owner="${owner}">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" delegateExpression="${myTaskListenerBean}">
            <activiti:field name="clientName" stringValue="${clientName}" />
            <activiti:field name="companyName" stringValue="${companyName}" />
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>

public class MyTaskCreateListener implements TaskListener {

    private String clientName;
    private String companyName;

    @Autowired
    private AdditionalTaskDataDao additionalTaskDataDao;

    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
        AdditionalTaskData taskData = new AdditionalTaskData();
        taskData.setClientName(clientName);
        taskData.setCompanyName(companyName);
        taskData.setTaskId(delegateTask.getId());

        myDataDao.save(taskData);
    }
}
```

**2:**

*Read:*

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(String.valueOf(processInstanceId)).active().singleResult();
Map<String, Object> variablesMap = runtimeService.getVariables(task.getExecutionId());
```

*Write:*

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(String.valueOf(processInstanceId)).active().singleResult();
runtimeService.setVariables(task.getExecutionId(), variablesMap);
```

Comment: I've one more doubt. Is there a way to create subtask to a task dynamically?